# random_pet in Terraform: Error: Cycle:

Tags: linux, automation, terraform

I am trying to generate random hostnames for a couple of servers. However when running terraform apply I get an error message "Error: Cycle: random_pet.swm01_managers, hcloud_server.swm01_managers"

This is what I am trying to do:

```
variable "swm01_managers_count" {
  default = 5
}

# ─── CREATE RANDOM SERVER HOSTNAMES ─────────────────────────────────────────────

resource "random_pet" "swm01_managers" {
  count = "${var.swm01_managers_count}"
  keepers = {
    id = "${hcloud_server.swm01_managers[count.index].id}"
  }
}

# ─── CREATE DOCKER SWARM MANAGER NODES ──────────────────────────────────────────

resource "hcloud_server" "swm01_managers" {
  count = "${var.swm01_managers_count}"

  name = "${random_pet.swm01_managers[count.index]}"
  image = "ubuntu-18.04"
  server_type = "cx11"
  ssh_keys = "${var.ssh_keys}"
  labels = {
    "env" = "prd"
    "docker_swarm_role" = "manager"
  }

}
```

Ans here's the error I get:

```
terraform apply --var-file=prd/prd.tfvars

Error: Cycle: random_pet.swm01_managers, hcloud_server.swm01_managers
```

Comment: This feels to me like it would probably be better at [sf].

Comment: All right. Thanks. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "swm01_managers_count" {
  default = 5
}

# ─── CREATE DOCKER SWARM MANAGER NODES ──────────────────────────────────────────

resource "hcloud_server" "swm01_managers" {
  count = var.swm01_managers_count

  name        = random_pet.swm01_managers[count.index].id
  image       = "ubuntu-18.04"
  server_type = "cx11"
  ssh_keys    = var.ssh_keys
  labels = {
    "env"              = "prd"
    "docker_swarm_role" = "manager"
  }
}

# ─── CREATE RANDOM SERVER HOSTNAMES ─────────────────────────────────────────────

resource "random_pet" "swm01_managers" {
  count = var.swm01_managers_count
  keepers = {
    id = hcloud_server.swm01_managers[count.index].id
  }

  # Add the depends_on attribute to explicitly set the dependency on hcloud_server.swm01_managers
  depends_on = [hcloud_server.swm01_managers]
}
```

By adding depends_on = [hcloud_server.swm01_managers] to the random_pet resource, you inform Terraform that the random_pet resource must be created after the hcloud_server.swm01_managers resources have been created. This will resolve the cyclic dependency issue, and Terraform should be able to apply your configuration successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).